# How to handle dart ui in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/material.dart:198:1: Error: 'platformViewRegistry' is exported from both 'dart:ui' and 'dart:ui_web'.
export 'dart:ui_web';

I'm facing this error .Code was working well but suddenly this happen

I dont know why it is happening

Comment: Please provide a snippet of your code, like you file header and pubspec.yaml

Comment: you cant use `dart:ui_web` for all platform. its  only available for web. it will throw error when you run on android or iOS.
if you still need to use the library, you need to use it separately